# IdentityServer login at ADFS with OAuth2 protocol

Tags: c#, oauth, identityserver4, identityserver3, adfs3.0

Currently a bit stuck on the following, hope somebody can point me in the right direction:

I'm trying to create an IdentityProvider which let's it's users login at ADFS. 
I want to use IdentityServer to provide session management and single sign-on,
manage and authenticate clients, issue identity and access tokens to clients, validate tokens.

I already have a controller which redirects users to their appropriate ADFS environment. After authentication users are coming back to the server with an access_code which I can exchange at ADFS for an access_token.

Now my issue here is: Where/ How can I fit in IdentityServer to take over functionality?

The targeted version is ADFS 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

BTW: Users will be forced to use ADFS, so I don't need an intermediary login page because they won't be able to choose from auth servers. They'll have to login at ADFS or not. This is why I already made the redirect.

Thanks in advance, any advice (or example) is welcome

Comment: Additionally, what version of ADFS do you have? If your version is ADFS 2016 (4.0) or higher, you may be able to do this directly with ADFS without needing Identity Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to federate ADFS and identityserver along [these lines](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-WS-Federation).

So the flow is application --> identityserver --> ADFS.